# Input mask for phone form field in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, zurb-foundation, input-mask

I have a customer contact form in my app which, of course, requires a phone input.  I am running Rails 3.2.13 and using Zurb Foundation.  I am hoping to find a gem that offers an input mask in the form '(999) 999-9999' that I can call.  My data is really local so the US formatted numbers is all that I need.

I am able to perform the validation on the field but wanted to keep the users within the tighter boundaries of an input mask.  This is what I have at the moment.

> ```
>   <div class="large-4 columns"><%= f.telephone_field :phone, :placeholder => "Phone - (123) 456-7890" %></div>
> ```

Any great gems for this, or perhaps a jQuery plugin that you like?

Cheers!

-Edit
So here is the full answer for what I needed to accomplish.  Just in case anyone is looking for a quick fix.  This is the code in my _form.html.erb view file:

```
<div class="large-2 columns">
   <%= f.text_field :phone, :id => "phone", :placeholder => "Primary Phone"%>
</div>
```

Here is the code in my coffee file in my assets/javascripts folder:

```
$ ->
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999")
```

You need to download the appropriate jquery.maskedinput.js file from the link @vinodadhikary mentions below.  Then you must require the file somewhere below the jquery file in the list of dependencies in your application.js file like so:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require jquery.maskedinput
//= require_tree .
```

That's about it.  If you notice anything amiss, please let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: Have a look at: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/.  Very nice plugin, check out the demo tab.

Comment: Much appreciated!  Looks perfect.

Comment: where do you add the `jquery.maskedinput.js` file? And I put the `.mask` function in the `x.coffee` where x is the controller where my form is. Is that correct? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the plugin http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin and it works pretty well.

I have a lot of fields with different masks so I use this method in my application coffescript.

```
  $( "[data-mask]").each (index, value) ->
    element = $(value)
    element.mask($(value).data('mask'))
```

Now I can just set a `data-mask` attribute on any of my fields::

```
      <%= f.text_field(:phone, data: { mask: '(999) 999-9999' }) %>
```

I hope this helps someone!